# Custom Intent-Filters in android

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

What i am currently try to achieve is:
Add a record in one activity and show it on the other activity.
And on the click of the edit button on the show activity it takes back user to the first page for editing the data.
The problem is that i cannot use Intent.putextra() for this because the add page is linked with other so it gives me error for this.
Thought of using shared preferences as well,but i don't think it would help me much, since if a  value is set in shared preference it would be available on load of the activity so i wont be able to know from where i entered the activity. so thought of using intent-filters for it.
can anyone help me with this ?
And i dont want to create another class for edit purpose.

Comment: Can't understand why you cannot use Intent extras.

Comment: Because i am getting null pointer exception if that activity get called from other activity and not from the view activity

Comment: You can just null-check the value - this way you'll understand what Activity has sent you that Intent.

Comment: tried it already but it gives me error when i read the extras foe eg i tried this code..'record=(Integer) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Id");'

Comment: it was a null pointer exception..sorry i wrote error instead of exception.anyways i am done with the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not check for...

```
<pre>
<code>
    if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Id") != null)
    {
       //get the data here becuz it's not null here....
    }
</code>
</pre>
```

also just note that [getIntExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) also exists...

Comment: got it done using intent filters..used something similar.using getAction() method.worked perfectly according to my need.